# Is there a unique finitely-additive extension of the length function to all real subsets?

Tags: measure-theory

It is known that the length function on closed, finite, real intervals cannot be extended to a $\sigma$-additive measure on $2^\mathbb{R}$ (hence the introduction of the Borel sets). But can it be extended to a finitely-additive measure on $2^\mathbb{R}$? If so, can it be extended uniquely, or at least in a "natural" way?

EDIT: Thanks to André Nicolas's hint below, i have found the following useful links:

1. [A question on this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53230/hahn-banach-to-extend-to-the-lebesgue-measure)
2. [An article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03023824#page-1)

Comment: Sure, Lebesgue measure on the reals can be so extended, in a translation invariant way. Old result of Banach, huge literature. Natural, well, not really.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks. Do you know if this is the way adopted by de-Finetti in his development of the theory of probability? I've read that he rejected $\sigma$-additivity.

Comment: Sorry, don't know. There may be a connection with probability, since quite a number of years ago, when I wrote a thin paper in the general area, I was surprised to get a a couple of offprint requests from people in statistics departments.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks. One more question, please, since it wasn't quite clear from your answer: is the Banach extension unique?

Comment: Quite non-unique, and requires a weak version of AC.