# A finitely additive measure which is translation invariant and measure of interval is equal to length of interval?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Does there exist such a measure on **all subsets** of R: A finitely additive measure which is translation invariant and measure of interval is equal to length of interval

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/540355/4280

Comment: To be honest, I do not like the answer you linked (and the answer linked from that). In the context of this question, it is not shown in the linked posts that the resulting finitely additive function is translation invariant (I think you will have to use a different form of Hahn-Banach to get that). Furthermore, it is not clear that the resulting function is nonnegative.

Comment: @PhoemueX I get the reference to study from book:The Banach Tarski Paradox by Stan Wagon. Its completely done in theorem 10.8